# How to handle method parameter if parameter is stored in object calling the method?

Tags: python

```
 Class Triple():

     def multiply(self, num1, num2, num3):
         return num1*num2*num3
```

If I ran something like:

```
mytriple = Triple()
print(mytriple.multiply(1,2,3))
```

I get `6`, which is all fine.

However what If my object itself is one of the parameters?

```
a = 3
print(a.multiply(2,3)) # Want it to print (3*2*3) = 18
```

I evidently get an error since a which is `3` an int, doesn't have the method I'm calling.

Is there a way I can still call the `multiply` method on an object that itself is one of the parameters?

Comment: Not if you want `a` to literally be `3`.

Comment: `mytriple.multiply(a, 2, 3)` would work just fine. Your method only is available on `Triple` instances, nowhere else.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to associate a `Triple` instance with a value (I don't know what exactly you are trying to do, this all seems like a contrived example) - you certainly can.

```
class Triple():
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def multiply(self, num1, num2):
         return self.value*num1*num2

mytriple = Triple(3)
print mytriple.multiply(2,3) # 18
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also subclass `int`:

```
class A(int):
    def multiply(self, *args):
        r = self
        for arg in args:
            r *= arg
        return r

>>> x = A(3)
>>> x.multiply(4,5)
60
>>> x.multiply(2,3,4)
72
```

This will then also behave like an `int` in other situations:

```
>>> x + 5
8
>>> x * 5
15
```